# Pandas: assign a datetime by condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have to assign a given datetime value into `timestamp` column to rows with NaT values if a condition is met in another column. All the values in `timestamp` are either `datetime64[ns]` or `NaT`.

#### EDIT:

sample data:

```
dates = [pd.to_datetime('2022-10-14 10:13:52', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
         pd.to_datetime('2022-10-14 17:43:52', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
         pd.to_datetime('2022-10-14 09:00:10', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
data = {'A': [-0.5, -0.5, 0.7, 1, 0.65, 0.5], 'timestamp': pd.Series(dates, index=[1, 3, 5])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Output:

```
      A           timestamp
0 -0.50                 NaT
1 -0.50 2022-10-14 10:13:52
2  0.70                 NaT
3  1.00 2022-10-14 17:43:52
4  0.65                 NaT
5  0.50 2022-10-14 09:00:10
```

I then do the following:

```
threshold = 0.65
null_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-09-01 09:00:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.timestamp = np.where(df.A >= threshold, null_date, df.timestamp)
```

However, this turns all the values in `timestamp` into object type.

```
      A            timestamp
0 -0.50                 None
1 -0.50  1665742432000000000
2  0.70  2022-09-01 09:00:00
3  1.00  2022-09-01 09:00:00
4  0.65  2022-09-01 09:00:00
5  0.50  1665738010000000000
```

That is, `NaTs` in rows where the condition is not met are replaced with `None`. `Datetime` in those rows are replaced, too. Only the rows where the condition was met get a `datetime`.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to replace NaT with a given datetime by condition?

#### EDIT-2:

It **worked out** with lambda function:

```
df.timestamp = df[['A', 'timestamp']].apply(lambda x: null_date if x['A'] >= threshold else x['timestamp'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      A           timestamp
0 -0.50                 NaT
1 -0.50 2022-10-14 10:13:52
2  0.70 2022-09-01 09:00:00
3  1.00 2022-09-01 09:00:00
4  0.65 2022-09-01 09:00:00
5  0.50 2022-10-14 09:00:10
```

Comment: Can you add a [mre]? From your code example, I'm having difficulties to understand how you're dealing with NaT. If you just want to replace those, use e.g. `fillna`.

Comment: You don't replace nat values ​​in the np.where function. What exactly is your expected output? Do you want to fill nat values ​​with null_date or do you want to fill those greater than or equal to threshold with null_date ?

Comment: @Clegane The latter. It does not matter what is in timestamp columns, NaT or datetime. I want to fill those greater than or equal to threshold (in column A) with null_date (into column timestamp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the **null_date** value does not match the type of the df['timestamp'] value. both must be datetime64. use this:

```
threshold = 0.65
null_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-09-01 09:00:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
null_date = np.datetime64(null_date)
df['timestamp'] = np.where(df['A'] >= threshold, null_date, df['timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = [pd.to_datetime('2022-10-14 10:13:52', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
         pd.to_datetime('2022-10-14 17:43:52', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
         pd.to_datetime('2022-10-14 09:00:10', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
data = {'A': [-0.5, -0.5, 0.7, 1, 0.65, 0.5], 'timestamp': pd.Series(dates, index=[1, 3, 5])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

threshold = 0.65
null_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-09-01 09:00:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#df.timestamp = np.where(df.A >= threshold, null_date, df.timestamp)
df.loc[df.A >= threshold, 'timestamp'] = null_date


>>> df
      A           timestamp
0 -0.50                 NaT
1 -0.50 2022-10-14 10:13:52
2  0.70 2022-09-01 09:00:00
3  1.00 2022-09-01 09:00:00
4  0.65 2022-09-01 09:00:00
5  0.50 2022-10-14 09:00:10
>>>
```